# How to resize in HTML

Tags: html, image, resize

I have a problem with my website aka a mod I want to make for a Game. When even i paste the image I want to be able to re size it to the max of the whole screen example: http://i61.tinypic.com/35hk7te.png The problem is I don't want to have that white space so here is an example how it should look like (different image): http://ponyquest.org/motd/index.html the mountain background is full.

Here is the code where I add the image:

```
<img src="http://oi58.tinypic.com/2wmou89.jpg" style="max-width:100%; max-height:100%;" alt="">
```

Comment: Isn't just using the `width` and `height` property what you are looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/YvQ5c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this add the following CSS rules:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

By default, the page has a foolowing top margin so this causes the whitespace, and this CSS code will reset it.

Here is what I did:

```
<html>
  <head>
 <title>NostalgiaRP LS</title>
 <style>
 html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
}
 </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--Put keywords in here to display when loading.-->
      keywords =
      [
       "Hacking Razley.",
       "Getting your credit card information.",
       "ED is coding your stuff!",  
       "Downloading a bunch of crap.",
       "Demoting admins.",
       "Fixing server bugs.",
       "Braking the game.",
       "Banning minges.",
       "Drawing ponies!:D.",
       "Checking your Steam ID.",
       "Removing System 32.",
       "Rehashing the MD5 algorithm.",
       "Bathing Father Grigori.",
       "Decrypting your steam account password.",
       "Re installing Garry's Mod.",
       "Killing Alyx.",
       "Reloading guns.",
       "Enter a useless message here!",
       "Asking for you to become an admin.",
       "Eating Watermelons.",
       "RDM.",
       "Fixing Source Engine.",
       "Drawing on walls.",
       "Taming Physics.",
       "Drinking Vodka...",
       "Sleeping.",
       "Fixing Gman's suit.",
       "Watching stuff and things...",
       "Reducing your lifespan.",
       "Joining the server.",
       "Delaying Episode 3.",
       "Uploading virus.",
       "......"
      ]


      var bCanChangeStatus = true;
      function ChangeText ( )  {
        if ( bCanChangeStatus )
        {
          var keyword = keywords[ Math.floor( Math.random() * keywords.length ) ]
          document.getElementById( "loadingtext" ).innerHTML = keyword;
        }

        setTimeout( "ChangeText()", 2500 );
      }

      ChangeText();

      var iFilesNeeded = 0;
      var iFilesTotal = 0;
      var bDownloadingFile = false;

      function SetFilesNeeded( iNeeded )
      {
        iFilesNeeded = iNeeded;
        RefreshFileBox();
      }

      function SetFilesTotal( iTotal )
      {
        iFilesTotal = iTotal;
        RefreshFileBox();
      }

      function DownloadingFile( filename )
      {
        if ( bDownloadingFile )
        {
          iFilesNeeded = iFilesNeeded - 1;
          RefreshFileBox();
        }

        document.getElementById( "loadingtext" ).innerHTML = "Downloading " + filename;
        bCanChangeStatus = false;
        setTimeout( "bCanChangeStatus = true;", 1000 );

        bDownloadingFile = true;

      }

      function SetStatusChanged( status )
      {
        if ( bDownloadingFile )
        {
          iFilesNeeded = iFilesNeeded - 1;
          bDownloadingFile = false;
          RefreshFileBox();
        }

        document.getElementById( "loadingtext" ).innerHTML = status;
        bCanChangeStatus = false;
        setTimeout( "bCanChangeStatus = true;", 1000 );
      }

      function RefreshFileBox()
      {
        document.getElementById( "files" ).innerHTML = "<img src='/images/loadingscreen/download.png' style='position: relative; top: 7px;'> " + iFilesNeeded + " downloads remaining";

        if ( iFilesTotal > 0 )
          document.getElementById( "files" ).style.visibility = 'visible';
        else
          document.getElementById( "files" ).style.visibility = 'hidden';
      }

      RefreshFileBox();

    </script>
        <iframe width="0%" height="0" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/16687438&amp;auto_play=true&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false&amp;visual=true"></iframe>

      <center>
      <div style="position: absolute;">
      <!-- Put the image URL here!!-->
    <img src="http://oi58.tinypic.com/2wmou89.jpg" style="height: 100%; max-width:100%; max-height:100%;" alt="">
    <div id="loadingtext" style="position:absolute; top:50%; left:50%; color: #666; font-family: Arial; font-size: 12px; margin-top:-6px; width:128px; margin-left:-64px; font-weight: bold;">Loading Text..</div>
</div>

        </div>
      </center>

      <div style='-webkit-box-reflect: below -120px -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(transparent), color-stop(0.1, transparent), to(rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.0))); position: absolute; top: 90%; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 5%; height: 100px; overflow: show; font-family: Arial; font-size: 24px; font-weight: bold; color: #888' id='files'>
      </div>

    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

And I get an image fitting the whole screen.

Comment: I am a bad when it comes to CSS where do I put it? Here is the whole code https://github.com/edgaraxe/NostalgiaRPRequest/blob/master/index.html

Comment: The easiest way is to add right before `</head>` this: `<style>YOUR CSS CODE HERE </style>`

Comment: Did not work sadly! it's still the same! </head>
  <style>
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
}  
</style>
  <body>

Comment: I edited my answer with your whole code inside it. It works fine for me. Just forgot to add `height: 100%` for the image.

Comment: BTW, just a quick tip. The tag <center> is not valid anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Im a little bit confused. Why not just use background-image:url('img url'); and then background-size:cover; on the element you want to add background image to?